# Generate push notification through Firebase

Tags: node.js, sails.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to generate a notification from my REST service. The drawback is that not send, although fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send responds that was successful.
This I do in two ways, first by the module http:

```
var http = require('http');
    var options = {
        'hostname': 'fcm.googleapis.com',
        'path': '/fcm/send',
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'key=<Key Server>',
            'Content-Type': "application/json"
        }
    };
    var data = {
        'to':tokenPush,
        'notification':notification
    };   
    var requestHttp = http.request(options, function(res){
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
        });
    });
    requestHttp.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    requestHttp.end(JSON.stringify(data));
```

The other way is through a command from the shell:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var     cmd = 'curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<Key Server>" ';
    cmd +=  '--Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send ';
    cmd +='-d \'{"to":"<Token Client>","notification":{"title":"Validación","body":"'+(new Date()).getTime()+'","sound":"default"}}\'';
    console.log("=====================================");
    console.log(cmd);
    console.log("=====================================");
    exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (error) {
          console.log("=====================================");
          console.error('exec error:'+error);

      }
        console.log("=====================================");
        console.log('stdout: '+stdout);
        console.log('stderr: '+stderr);
    });
```

In both cases the answer is:

{ "Multicast_id":  "success": 1, "failure": 0, "canonical_ids": 0, "results": [{ "message_ID": ""}]}.

The code for the shell works correctly when I run it from a separate file with the "node" command.

What I can be wrong?

Comment: Did you have errors in node?
You have error in "requestHttp var = http.request (options, function "
replace to 
 "var requestHttp = http.request (options, function "

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But ignoring this error copy-paste, still does not send the notification, although the service was successful Firebase answer.

Comment: Try code from my answer

Comment: Is my answer slove you problem?

Comment: No. The code already was as you described, but it still did not work.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an fcm wrapper. I've used 'fcm-node' link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node

Just install it with `npm install fcm-node --save`

**Usage**

```html
var FCM = require('fcm-node');

var serverKey = '';
var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);

var message = { //this may vary according to the message type (single recipient, multicast, topic, et cetera)
    to: 'registration_token', 
    collapse_key: 'your_collapse_key',
    
    notification: {
        title: 'Title of your push notification', 
        body: 'Body of your push notification' 
    },
    
    data: {  //you can send only notification or only data(or include both)
        my_key: 'my value',
        my_another_key: 'my another value'
    }
};

fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
    }
});
```

Comment: With the module that you indicate is simpler, but still does not send notifications. For the above two algorithms, FCM service also indicated that the process was successful.

FCM service informs that the process is successful, but the messages are not displayed on the device. I think it's a matter own service, which prevents send notifications in a small time period.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not clean.

This should work. Replace **CLIENT_PUSH_ID** and **YOUR_AUTH_KEY** to real

```html
var http = require('http');
var message = {
    "to": "CLIENT_PUSH_ID",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Validación",
        "body": (new Date()).getTime(),
        "sound": "default"
    }
};
var postData = JSON.stringify(message);
var options = {
    hostname: 'fcm.googleapis.com',
    path: '/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': postData.length,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'key=YOU_AUTH_KEY'
    }
};

var requestHttp = http.request(options, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
    res.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('error:' + e.message);
    });
});
requestHttp.write(postData);
requestHttp.end();

requestHttp.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: This code is not clean to prevent key server and the token of the test device was seen by all the world. Thank you for your comment.